# Model Validation is working even without ModelState.IsValid netcore3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-validation

I wouldn't say this is a problem but something I'm just curious about.
So I've just started using .net for web api's, I'd normally use node or python cause they're faster to build, pretty awesome so far.

Anyway in my controller method (post), Adding a (ModelState.IsValid) condition doesnt make a difference.

I mean the code still validates the model, but the post controller method isnt even doing anything. Hopefully the code makes it clearer.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEntityRepository _entityRepository;

    public PeopleController(IEntityRepository entityRepository)
    {
        _entityRepository = entityRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Person> Create(Person person) 
    {
        // if(!ModelState.IsValid){
        //     return new OkObjectResult("wrong shit");
        // } 
        // person.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        // person.Tags = new List<string>();
        // person.Tags.Add($"id+@{person.Id}");
        // person.Tags.Add($"ar+:-{person.Archived}");
        // person.Id = MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
        // _entityRepository.Create(person);
        // return person;
        return null;
    }

}


public interface IEntityRepository {

   void Create(Person person);

}

public class EntityRepository : IEntityRepository
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Person> _entities;
    public EntityRepository(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("TestConn"));
        var database = client.GetDatabase("TestDB");
        _entities = database.GetCollection<Person>("Person");
    }

    public void Create(Person person)
    {
        _entities.InsertOne(person);
    }
}


public class Person : IEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Name must be longer than 10 characters")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Name must be shorter than 20 characters")]
    public string Name {get;set; }
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Enter valid email")]
    [ValidEmail(AllowedDomain = "gmail.com", ErrorMessage = "Invalid email")]
    public string Email {get;set;}
    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone")]
    public string phone {get;set;}
    [BsonElement("archived")]
    public bool Archived { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("tags")]
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [BsonElement("something")]
    public Something Rotation {get;set;}
}
```

When i add this to postman

```
{
    "name": "sssssssssssssssssss",
    "phone": "2323-2323-2323",
    "email": "sd@gmail.com",
    "rotation": { "name": "g"}
}
```

It still validates

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|b6721095-496abaabbf3dbf66.",
    "errors": {
        "Rotation.Name": [
            "The field Name must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '10'."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand the problem, but the validation comes from the validation attributes such as [Required], [Phone] ... and so on that you applied on your `Person` class properties. IsValid is a way to check if the input is valid or not and has noting to do with enabling or disabling validation. To disable validation check the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#disable-validation

Comment: There's not really a problem per se, I'm just trying to understand some docs and tutorials. Getting confused on why people are using ModelState.IsValid when the validation attributes are doing just fine? Or could it be that ModelState is just used in the view to redirect or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, just saw this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Web API controllers don't have to check ModelState.IsValid if they have the [ApiController] attribute. In that case, an automatic HTTP 400 response containing issue details is returned when model state is invalid. For more information, see Automatic HTTP 400 responses.